# Will GetMessage() return -1 in main message loop?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

According to the [GetMessage API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644936%28VS.85%29.aspx) from MSDN Library, it might returns -1 when there is an error. The document provides a code snippet of common error that should be avoid:

```
while (GetMessage( lpMsg, hWnd, 0, 0)) ...
```

Document says:

> The possibility of a -1 return value
>   means that such code can lead to fatal
>   application errors. Instead, use code
>   like this:

```
BOOL bRet;
while( (bRet = GetMessage( &msg, hWnd, 0, 0 )) != 0)
{ 
    if (bRet == -1)
    {
        // handle the error and possibly exit
    }
    else
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg); 
        DispatchMessage(&msg); 
    }
}
```

My question is, in every sample code, including default application created from Visual Studio, from Microsoft, the main message loop looks like below:

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

Notice that the 2nd parameter of GetMessage above is NULL. If the code above is valid, does this mean that GetMessage here will NEVER returns -1 so that dealing with return value of -1 is not necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that VS gives you wrong code by default, and nobody seems to care, it is very likely that this causes no trouble *in current versions of Windows*.

It is possible that some future version of `GetMessage` *will* return -1. However, since the erroneous code must be in so many existing applications by now, this would break a huge amount of existing code. Given Microsoft's dedication to backwards compatibility, I think it's highly unlikely that they'll change the behaviour of `GetMessage` that so many programs are relying upon.

And in spite of all that, you should still follow the documentation.

Comment: I never ran into trouble by not checking return of -1, but when I saw the document, I am confused.

Right now, I am stick with what document says. And ASSERT() when GetMessage returns -1.

Comment: The VS generated code for a default application is correct since it doesn't pass any filters and provides a valid `MSG*`-argument. If you read the documentation for [`GetMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936.aspx) it explicitly names those 2 error modes. Further down where it reads *"avoid code like this:"* it shows an example with a `HWND` filter. Other error modes are possible, but those are catastrophic and cannot reasonably be handled anyway. Or how would you recover from a corrupted message queue? At that point it is Game Over, 2P UP.

Answer (score 4):

You should follow the rules specified in the MSDN documentation for `GetMessage()`. It's painless to do so and it's not as if you have large numbers of message loops scattered about your code.

The Visual Studio team are separate to the Windows team and they make the same mistakes as everyone else!

I reality I can't ever imagine `GetMessage()` returning an error, but that is the nature of error handling – that doesn't mean you shouldn't handle errors properly.

Comment: I just found that there is a series of articles from MSDN called "Learn to Program for Windows in C++". And the [BaseWindow Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff485838(v=VS.85).aspx) does not check for return value of -1 in the main message loop.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation you mention says:

> If there is an error, the return value is -1. For example, the function fails if *hWnd* is an invalid window handle or *lpMsg* is an invalid pointer.

In your second example, those two cases are covered: `msg` is a typical stack-allocated structure, so `&msg` will always be a valid pointer. `NULL` is passed in the `hwnd` parameter and is an accepted value for that parameter. `wMsgFilterMin` and `wMsgFilterMax` are both zero, which also is a valid combination.

So `GetMessage()` won't fail during parameter validation. The documentation does not clearly mention if it also returns `-1` in other situations (memory exhausted, for example). That said, I've been calling `GetMessage()` in the same way as your second example for a while now and I never, ever, saw it returning `-1` and turning my message loop into an infinite loop. Your mileage may vary, of course, but it seems quite safe to do that.

Comment: Almost all projects I am working on do not check return for -1, so I think I am fairly safe.

Answer (score 3):

My gut (aka [Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/) psychic powers) tells me that `GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)` will only return -1 in the case of an extremely rare catastrophic failure, like corruption of the message queue. In that case, testing for it is somewhat like catching std::bad_alloc in a C++ program: when it happens it's probably too late to do anything about it. Letting the process hang (by ignoring GetMessage() == -1) or die (by not catching bad_alloc) is acceptable, unless of course said process is controlling a nuclear power plant.

It all depends on how formal you want to be. I would specifically test for -1 in a commercial application, but not in a little utility written for personal use.

Comment: If nuclear power plants ran on Windows, we'd all be dead by now.