# WM_QUIT only posts for thread and not the window?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, message-queue

In Windows API, I'm looking into how the `GetMessage` function actually works.  I've seen 3 implementations of the Windows message loop and would like to explore them.

---

#### 1)

As of the time of writing this post, [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644928(v=vs.85).aspx) describes what I believe to be the *correct* way to implement the message loop.

```
MSG msg;
BOOL bRet;
while( (bRet = GetMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 )) != 0)
{ 
    if (bRet == -1)
    {
        // handle the error and possibly exit
    }
    else
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg); 
        DispatchMessage(&msg); 
    }
}
```

---

#### 2)

On the [`GetMessage` function page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936(v=vs.85).aspx), I see this implementation:

```
MSG msg;
BOOL bRet;
while( (bRet = GetMessage( &msg, hWnd, 0, 0 )) != 0)
{ 
    if (bRet == -1)
    {
        // handle the error and possibly exit
    }
    else
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg); 
        DispatchMessage(&msg); 
    }
}
```

---

#### 3)

Last, the [Visual Studio documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx) has this implementation as part of their Win32 Application demonstration.

```
MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

---

#### Discussion

In short, implementation #3 disregards errors returned from `GetMessage`, but otherwise works the same as the first implementation.  That is, they both process all messages for the current thread.  And when the `GetMessage` function returns `0`, the loops terminate.

Since I found implementation #2 before #1, I thought it was complete.  However, I've noticed that `GetMessage` does not return `0` when the `WM_QUIT` message is posted via [`PostQuitMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644945(v=vs.85).aspx)

This led to a bit of confusion, until I found implementation #1 and tested it.  The difference between the first two implementations is the 2nd parameter to `GetMessage`.  In #2, it specifies the `hWnd`, which according to the `GetMessage` documentation is:

> A handle to the window whose messages are to be retrieved. The window must belong to the current thread.

In #1, it is `NULL`, which pertains to this excerpt:

> If hWnd is NULL, GetMessage retrieves messages for any window that belongs to the current thread, and any messages on the current thread's message queue whose hwnd value is NULL (see the MSG structure). Therefore if hWnd is NULL, both window messages and thread messages are processed.

When testing using `NULL`, the `GetMessage` function returns `0` when the `WM_QUIT` message is processed, successfully terminating the loop.

#### Questions

1. Even though `PostQuitMessage` is called from a particular window's callback function, does `WM_QUIT` actually belong to the window or the current thread?  Based on testing these three implementations, it appears to be associated with the current thread.
2. If associated with the thread, when it is useful or appropriate to use a valid `hWnd` as a parameter to `GetMessage`?  Such a message loop would not be able to return `0` as a reaction to `WM_QUIT`, so is there another way that the message loop should terminate?

#### References

- [`GetMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [`PostQuitMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644945(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Message Loop #1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644928(v=vs.85).aspx) [(Wikipedia Link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows)
- [Message Loop #2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Message Loop #3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx)
- [`WM_QUIT` Message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632641(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5288285)

#### Code

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR cmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    LPCTSTR wndClassName =_T("Class_SHTEST");
    LPCTSTR wndName = _T("SHTest");

    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_ARROW));
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) COLOR_WINDOW+1;
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = wndClassName;
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("Call to RegisterClassEx failed!"), wndName, MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    HWND window = CreateWindow(wndClassName, wndName,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_MAXIMIZE, 
        0, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("Call to CreateWindow failed!"), wndName, MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    ShowWindow(window, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(window);

    //Message loop (using implementation #1)
    MSG msg;
    BOOL bRet;
    while((bRet = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) != 0) {
        if (bRet == -1) {
            //Handle error and possibly exit.
        }
        else {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    //Return the exit code in the WM_QUIT message.
    return (int) msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: Hmya, everybody knows that a BOOL can be FALSE, TRUE or FileNotFound.  If you get -1 then you are doing it really wrong, nothing you can handle.   Not getting 0 from GetMessage() when you use PostQuitMessage() is really wrong too.  You'll need to post repro code.  Or use a library, writing reliable Win32 code today is rocket science that should be left to somebody that has to support it.

Comment: @HansPassant Could you please elaborate what makes those scenarios wrong?  I've gone ahead and appended my post with some code.

Comment: Use #3. Since you are passing NULL for the window handle, and a valid MSG variable, GetMessage cannot return -1. Read Raymond Chen's article on the subject.

Comment: [When will GetMessage return -1?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/03/22/10404367.aspx). Raymond Chen's blog also has several articles on how `WM_QUIT` and `PostQuitMessage()` operate, and how to use them correctly in message loops.

Comment: Interesting.  That would explain why I was receiving -1 as a return value when I pass an hWnd and attempt to close that window.  That should mean I only need to check for -1 when not using a completely unfiltered message pump (i.e. not `GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)`)

Comment: Link went dead.  It is the article published on March 22, 2013. See: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130322-00/?p=4873

Comment: @NicholasMiller Microsoft changed the links again, it's now at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130322-00/?p=4873 hopefully, it stays there, so future references keep working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the [MSDN documention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632641%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of `WM_QUIT`:

> The WM_QUIT message is not associated with a window and therefore will
>   never be received through a window's window procedure. It is retrieved
>   only by the GetMessage or PeekMessage functions.

Since `WM_QUIT` is not associated with a window, and passing an `HWND` to `GetMessage()` only retrieves those messages associated with that window, the latter will never receive `WM_QUIT` by design.

As for when you would want to pass an `HWND` to `GetMessage()`, in a general message loop for an application you wouldn't. But there are times when you want to pump messages while something in the UI is happening, and are only concerned with messages that are associated with a specific window.

Answer (score 5):

`WM_QUIT` is relevant to a thread, not an individual window. Note the lack of a `hwnd` parameter for `PostQuitMessage()`. There's no way it could be window-specific because there is no way to tell it which window to generate the message for.

`WM_QUIT` is not actually a real message. When you call `PostQuitMessage()` an internal flag is set in the message queue state that `WM_QUIT` has been requested. This will be auto-generated by `GetMessage()` or `PeekMessage()` at some point in the future (often immediately, but if the queue contains other posted messages these will be processed first).

This is explained in more detail on [Raymond Chen's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/11/04/489028.aspx), which also contains the following quote:

> As another special behavior, the generated WM_QUIT message bypasses
>   the message filters passed to the GetMessage and PeekMessage
>   functions. If the internal "quit message pending" flag is set, then
>   you will get a WM_QUIT message once the queue goes quiet, regardless
>   of what filter you pass.

This suggests that your observations are wrong, and that `GetMessage()` in your example #2 above should return 0 after `PostQuitMessage()` is called even though a filter parameter has been provided.

In general you should only use message filters if you have a specific need for them (e.g. you specifically want to retrieve a message posted to a particular window). In most cases those parameters should all be set to 0 for normal functioning of your UI.

Comment: It is interesting to see that WM_QUIT is not a normal message.    In regards to your quote, I believe the filter mentioned is what is specified by the last 2 parameters of `Getmessage` (wMsgFilterMin  & wMsgFilterMax).  It does not appear to me that the `HWND` parameter should be included as part of that filter even though it restricts which messages are retrieved.  Unfortunately, I have no reliable way to test filtering.  In my test for implementation #2, I logged all return values for `GetMessage` and `0` did not appear once.  This is consistent with WM_QUIT being thread-relevant.

Comment: @NickMiller I agree it's not completely clear, although all three parameters can be considered filters in the sense that they control which messages the functions return.